# Read keys pressed into string

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard

**Edit**: I rewrote the question to make it understandable.

I'm trying to capture certain pressed keys in my WPF application so I've registered an eventhandler in my main window.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(OnButtonKeyDown);
}
```

The eventhandler itself looks like this.

```
private void OnButtonKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // I'd like the char value here.
}
```

My problem is that I'm not able to extract the char of the key that is pressed. Only the key code. KeyEventArgs obviously does not have such a property.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Wouldn't you just use `var keyPress = Console.Read()`?  Maybe I'm missing your objective here...

Comment: Did you want the character value? In which case `Console.WriteLine(" Your key is: {0}", (int) keypress.KeyChar)`

Comment: Well... Someone edited the question so it doesn't say anymore that it is a WPF application and not a console application

Comment: @Anders What are you trying to print the `KeyChar` into?  A textbox?  A gridview?  Your code example shows a `Console` example, so that's what people are answering.  Please update your context.

Comment: @EvanL I did a total rewrite

Comment: @Anders Thanks, that helps.  e.Key.ToString() should give you what you are looking for (as seen in Beaker's answer).

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to use the line e.Key.ToString() to get the character value of the key pressed.  Then you can use Char.TryParse(string input, out charValue) to verify you have a valid character and not something like "Numpad0."

Comment: It might work for some keys but you might also get results like `Numpad0` instead of 0 if you go this way.

Comment: See additional clarification in my answer.